# Integrating jQuery fullcalendar into PHP website

Tags: php, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

I would like to integrate the jQuery fullcalendar into my PHP website, but I don't know how to handle the event and how to use the JSON data from MySQL.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it this calender you're referring to? http://www.redredred.com.au/projects/jquery-week-calendar/

Comment: If it's really urgent, you should try the IRC channel http://blog.jquery.com/2007/02/17/the-jquery-irc-channel/ ...

Comment: Why would we care if the task is urgent? For me, that's usually a reason *not* to answer the question. If you need something done quickly, find yourself some paid support.

Comment: @elzapp 
Yes, it's just that plugin.

Comment: @Duroth 
Yes, you are right. I have been suffering it since several days. And i'm here for more ideas and advice. I appreciate your suggestions very much.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make sure that your PHP can output the f[ollowing HTML code](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Calendar):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
                    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#example').calendar();
  });
  </script>

</head>
<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/themes/flora/flora.all.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="Flora (Default)">
<script  src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/calendar/jquery-calendar.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="example" value="Click inside me to see a calendar" style="width:300px;"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's [a sample](http://silverstripe.org/general-questions/show/264599) how you can do it, by using json_encode:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ 
         draggable: true, 
         events: "json_events.php", 
         eventDrop: function(event, delta) { 
            alert(event.title + ' was moved ' + delta + ' days\n' + 
               '(should probably update your database)'); 
         }, 
         loading: function(bool) { 
            if (bool) $('#loading').show(); 
            else $('#loading').hide(); 
         } 
      }); 

   });
```

And here's the PHP code:

```
<?php

   $year = date('Y'); 
   $month = date('m');

   echo json_encode(array( 

      array( 
         'id' => 1, 
         'title' => "Event1", 
         'start' => "$year-$month-10", 
         'url' => "http://yahoo.com/" 
      ), 

      array( 
         'id' => 2, 
         'title' => "Event2", 
         'start' => "$year-$month-20", 
         'end' => "$year-$month-22", 
         'url' => "http://yahoo.com/" 
      ) 

   ));

?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. But i think you have some misunderstanding or i didn't describe it very clearly.

I want to add the jquery weekcalendar plugin and there is a sample for it. Everything is in session there. But i want to make it work with mysql database.

Thanks a lot!!!!!!!

Comment: depending on the server make sure you have `date_default_timezone_set('America/YOUR_TZ');` before the `date(XXX)` call

Answer (score 9):

"2010-02-11 11:00:00" format works fine to specify time for me (without "T" inside),
the key of the solution is to set the "allDay" attribute of an event to empty string.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and just found out how to make it work.
Here is the code that you should use in your php file:

```
$query = "select * from events where accountNo = '$accountNo'";
$res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$events = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $start = "2010-01-08T08:30"";//Here you have to format data from DB like this.
    $end = "2010-01-08T08:30";//This format works fine
    $title = $row['firstName']." ".$row['lastName'];
    $eventsArray['id'] =  $row['id'];
    $eventsArray['title'] = $title;
    $eventsArray['start'] = $start;
    $eventsArray['end'] = $end;
    $eventsArray['allDay'] = "";
    $events[] = $eventsArray;
}


echo json_encode($events);
```

I hope it helps :).

Answer (score 3):

In PHP - JSON:

```
$eventsArray['allDay'] = "false"; //doesn't work

$eventsArray['allDay'] = false; //did the trick to have a NON FULL DAY correctly rendered!!
```

Answer (score 1):

the output to echo an event should be in this format:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  events: [{
    title: 'Awesome Event Title', 
    start: new Date($start_year, $start_month, $start_day),     or   end: new Date(y, m, d),
    end: new Date($end_year, $end_month, $end_day)    or   end: new Date(y, m, d)
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

implement it this way and it works fine

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM eventoform",$conexion);
        $array = array();
        $i = 0;
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $array[$i]=array("id"=>$row["id_evento"],"title"=>$row["NombreEvento"],"start"=>$row["FechaInicio"]." ".$row["HoraInicio"],"allDay"=>false,"description"=>$row["description"],"editable"=>true);
            $i++;
        }

 echo json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with jquery. But I *think* the problem is that you are not taking into account the asynchronous nature of Ajax.

Unless fullCalendar() does something very odd (fires off an Ajax request and waits for the response), then you will not be able to use an external source in the function in that way, because fullCalendar will have finished running by the time a response comes back from the server.

There does not appear to be a clear example of what you are trying to do on the Week Calendar webpage, but I am sure that what you need is to create the calendar without the events, but with a callback defined for adding events; and then in some way fire off the external call.

Comment: Thanks for your post. You kind of have indicated my problem. Actually, I can't add/edit/delete the events and can't grab the data from mysql in the way of json.  I'll try to arrange and solve it. And thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your having the same problem as I'm having. I've search the web trying to find out how to setup the DateTime so that the fullCalendar javascript will interpret it correctly. (This page had some good clues to that: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format).

I posted this on the fullCalendar issues page hoping that the creator or anyone else would shed some light on the subject.

====================ISSUE DESCRIPTION====================

What steps will reproduce the problem?

1. Fetch events using JSON
2. use this JSON string:

```
[{"id":2, "title":"title of 2","start":"2009-11-17T10:00:00" ,"end":"2009-11-17T11:01:00","url":"?eventID=2"}]
```

What is the expected output? What do you see instead?

- I expect that the event will show up in the calendar with start time
  10:00 and end time 11:01.
- It show up as an all day event.

What version of the product are you using? On what operating system?

- FullCalendar v1.4.1
- Windows XP

Please provide any additional information below.

I am using an aspx page for fetching the calendar events. My guess is that
there is something wrong with the format of the JavaScript `DateTime` object
that I'm returning in the `JSON` and that this is causing the `fullcalendar` to
interpret the events as `fullDayEvents`. The format that I'm sending in the
`JSON` is: `2009-11-17T11:01:00`.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, I have not used your code above, but in json_events.php the default one, **there is 
"[" in the start of php output and "]" on the end**.

Answer (score 0):

This example works:

```
$sql= "SELECT id, title, start, DATE_FORMAT(start, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i' ) AS startDate
FROM kalender
ORDER BY startDate DESC";
$res = mysql_db_query($db, $sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());

$events = array();
//important ! $start = "2010-05-10T08:30";  iso8601 format !!
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
   $eventArray['id'] = $row['id'];
   $eventArray['title'] =  $row['title'];
   $eventArray['start'] = $row['startDate'];
   $events[] = $eventArray;
}
echo json_encode($events);
```

Answer (score 0):

just in case there is someone using rails with jbuilder to generate the json feed...you have to **add the allDay attribute** ...

```
json.array!(@resubmissions) do |object|
  json.id object.id
  json.title "WVL - #{object.to_s}"
  json.start object.resubmission_at.to_i
  json.allDay false
end
```

However, thanks for the PHP solution!