# fullCalendar json with php in "agendaWeek"

Tags: jquery, xml, json, date, fullcalendar

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='fullcalendar/redmond/theme.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='fullcalendar/jquery/jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='fullcalendar/jquery/ui.core.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='fullcalendar/jquery/ui.draggable.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='fullcalendar/jquery/ui.resizable.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

 $(document).ready(function() {

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

   theme: true,
   editable: false,
   weekends: false,
   allDaySlot: false,
   allDayDefault: false,
   slotMinutes: 15,
   firstHour: 8,
   minTime: 8,
   maxTime: 17,
   height: 600,
   defaultView: 'agendaWeek',

   events: "json_events.php",

   loading: function(bool) {
    if (bool) $('#loading').show();
    else $('#loading').hide();
   }

  });

 });

</script>
```

But the informaion will not show up on  the "agendaWeek".
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong.

My "json_events.php" code is:

```
<?php

 $year = date('Y');
 $month = date('m');

 echo json_encode(array(

  array(
   'id' => 111,
   'title' => "Event1",
   'start' => "$year-$month-22 8:00",
   'end' => "$year-$month-22 12:00",
   'url' => "http://yahoo.com/"
  ),

  array(
   'id' => 222,
   'title' => "Event2",
   'start' => "$year-$month-22 14:00",
   'end' => "$year-$month-22 16:00",
   'url' => "http://yahoo.com/"
  )

 ));

?>
```

And it out puts the following:

```
[{"id":111,"title":"Event1","start":"2010-03-22 8:00","end":"2010-03-22 12:00","url":"http:\/\/yahoo.com\/"},{"id":222,"title":"Event2","start":"2010-03-22 14:00","end":"2010-03-22 16:00","url":"http:\/\/yahoo.com\/"}]
```

Please if anyone can help or suggest someone to help me.

Thanks,
Dennis

Answer (score 7):

Set the "allDay" attribute of an event to empty string.  (Setting to false does not work.)

See: [Integrating jQuery fullcalendar into PHP website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666146/integrating-jquery-fullcalendar-into-php-website)

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify allDay to false, e.g.:

```
[
    {
        "id": 111,
        "title": "Event1",
        "start": "2010-03-22 08:00",
        "end": "2010-03-22 12:00",
        "url": "http://yahoo.com/",
        "allDay": false
    },
    {
        "id": 222,
        "title": "Event2",
        "start": "2010-03-22 14:00",
        "end": "2010-03-22 16:00",
        "url": "http://yahoo.com/",
        "allDay": false
    }
]
```

See: [Integrating jQuery fullcalendar into PHP website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666146/integrating-jquery-fullcalendar-into-php-website)